# How to use RouteConfig to append a page URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am struggling to get my code work, but I think I've read enough to suggest this is the correct way to approach this.

On my intranet, I'd like the user to type in a single word to search into a textbox, and check a `checkbox`. When the new page loads, I'd like the URL rewritting services of ASP.NET MVC to kick in and change a value from

```
mysite.com/?id=blah&isChecked=true
```

to

```
mysite.com/home/index/blah/true
```

My code isn't working in the sense of it gives no error, but doesn't do what I am explaining. So, I've removed the check box to just focus on the textbox.

My only route is

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{MyType}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", MyType = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

My Controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this";
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string MyType)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "..." + MyType;

        return View();
    }
```

and my View has

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home",FormMethod.Get))
{ 
    <input name="MyType" /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
}

@Html.ActionLink("Click me", "Index", new { @MyType = "Blah" }) //renders correctly
```

The problem is, it shows the querystring still in the address bar

```
mysite.com/?MyType=MySearchValue
```

instead of

```
mysite.com/Home/Index/MySearchValue
```

Comment: Your `MyType` input needs to have attribute `name="MyType"`.

Comment: You input needs a name attribute in order to post back a value `<input id="MyType" name="MyType" />`

Comment: Thank you @AntP and Stephen Muecke, I have made this change but the 'main' issue still persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this purely with routing because the browser will always send form values as query string parameters when they are part of a GET request. Once the request has been sent to the server, the MVC framework can't do anything about the URL that was used.

This leaves you with only one real option (assuming you don't want to send a custom request using JavaScript), which is to explicitly redirect to the desired URL (meaning you will always have two requests when this form is submitted).

The simplest way of doing this is simply in the controller (rather, in a separate controller to ensure that there is no conflict in method signatures):

```
public class FormController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string MyType)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyProperController", new { MyType });
    }
}
```

If you direct your form to this controller action, MVC will then use the routing engine to generate the proper URL for the *real* action and redirect the browser accordingly.

You could do this from the same controller action but it would involve inspecting the request URL to check whether a query string was used or not and redirecting back to the same action, which is a little odd.

Comment: See also [specifications for the form submission method](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#submit-format)